# How do I get my AWS Bitnami Magento deploy to load assets with https?

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, https, varnish, bitnami

I have setup an AWS Bitnami Magento deploy which is using **Application Load Balancer** and **host name routing** to use **https** but the site insists on loading **.css** and **.js** assets via **http** which is blocked by the browser unless I manually tell it to load.

I have read about turning off **Varnish** and adding a few settings to **Apache** but I'm wary of experimentation. Has anyone got their deploy to load assets via **https** by turning off **Varnish**?

It seems a bit like throwing the baby out with the bath water to remove such a good http accelerator... and sites do use **https** with it, e.g.  The New York Times.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Did you edit the Magento code to load those custom .css and .js files? In case you did, it's important to mention that you should have used HTTPS when referencing those new .css and .js files because in case you used HTTP, you will receive a warning when accessing your site using HTTPS

Comment: Hi Jota, I was pulled away with other tasks and I will check again first thing in the morning.